# Is there an idiom or saying meaning the opposite of "the grass is always greener on the other side"?

Tags: idiom-requests

I'm looking for an adage that describes a situation where a group is blind to their own faults or situation but readily discerns those same faults and situations in a rival.

This picture basically sums it up:
[image: Ours vs. Theirs]

The grass is *browner* on the other side?

Comment: There's the KJV:  "And why beholdest thou the mote that is in thy brother's eye, but considerest not the beam that is in thine own eye?"

Comment: @Jim This is pretty close to what I'm looking for. If only it were shorter... I just found a good one, but it's in Latin: _meretrix pudicam_.

Comment: I suppose I might have to settle for "The pot called the kettle black."

Comment: Actually, the grass is always brown on the other side.

Comment: @saltface -  I don't know Meretrix or her cats. I wonder if her cams are anything like these: https://catmospherelaguna.com/kitty-cam.php

Comment: As far as I can tell, the answer should have two aspects when the cartoon is taken into consideration; the feeling of superiority when there's nothing to feel superior about and the blindness to the whole situation. "the pot called the kettle black" is _almost_ perfect but I can't say the pot is feeling superior.

Answer (score 3):

I think the saying that best expresses the opposite of things being better *elsewhere* is [**there's no place like home**](https://www.theidioms.com/theres-no-place-like-home/):

> [The Idioms]
>
> Meaning
>
> - to have an affinity for one’s home over every other place
> - to say that the home is the best place
> - to say that one’s home is beyond compare

Of course, the saying became much more popular thanks to the movie [*The Wizard of Oz*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4cWKkjTzukM).

You could say *nobody does it better than us* or *we're the greatest*, but those aren't actually idioms.

---

Related would be [**they can't hold a candle to us**](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/183700.html):

> [The Phrase Finder]
>
> What's the meaning of the phrase 'Hold a candle'?
>         The expression 'can't hold a candle to' refers to someone who compares badly to an known authority - to be unfit even to hold a subordinate position.
>
> What's the origin of the phrase 'Hold a candle'?
>         Apprentices used to be expected to hold the candle so that more experienced workmen were able to see what they were doing. Someone unable even to do that would be of low status indeed.

This particular phrase implies a certain level of disparagement toward everyone else that the first phrase does not.

Answer (score 0):

Since childhood, I have understood "The grass is always greener on the other side of the fence" to be an explanation of why cattle are so eager to slip around, over, or through fences into the neighbor's pasture. That, at any rate, is the explantion that my grandfather gave me when I was very young and visiting him on his farm in central Texas.

If so, an idiomatic way to make the opposite gastronomic observation might be this:

> **There is no cooking like home cooking.**

I found an occurrence of this expression presented as truism in "[As We Strolled](https://books.google.com/books?id=uTTmAAAAMAAJ&pg=RA3-PT64&dq=%22no+cooking+like+home+cooking%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiX9NvSwbXiAhVrHTQIHUPoCroQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22no%20cooking%20like%20home%20cooking%22&f=false)," in the *[Anamosa, Iowa] Reformatory Press* (July 17, 1909):

> Cellhouse Custodian Knight is now a grass widower. His wife is away on  visit to her sister in Cedar Rapids. **There is no cooking like home-cooking**.

A Google Books search finds seven matches for the phrase from between 1959 and 2002; and an Elephind newspaper database search finds six additional instances from between 1918 and 1965, including a couple of portmanteau versions:

> Be it ever so humble, **there's no cooking like home cooking**.

(from the [*St. Jo [Texas] Tribune*](https://texashistory.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metapth335208/m1/2/zoom/?q=%22no%20cooking%20like%20home%20cooking%22&resolution=4&lat=3892&lon=2620) (November 13, 1959), and

> There's no place like home and **no cooking like home cooking**.

from the [*[Abilene, Texas] Hardin-Simmons University Brand*](https://texashistory.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metapth98634/m1/1/zoom/?q=%22no%20cooking%20like%20home%20cooking%22&resolution=4&lat=3439.5&lon=2237.5) (November 19, 1965).

Comment: I just have to give a shout-out to the _St. Jo [Texas] Tribune_ for offering what may be the most poignant headline ever run in a small-town newspaper—and it just happens to be on the same page where the "no cooking like home cooking" quotation appears: "Former St. Jo Man Is Successful."